# Dynamic injection in Spring

Tags: spring

I have 2 tax implementation classes `IndianTaxCalculation` and `USTAxCalculation` which have implementaions for `calculateTax()` method. I need to populate the class dynamically based on user login whether Indian or US, the respective Tax calculation method should call. How can i achieve this in Spring?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("indian")
private TaxCalculation indianTax;
@Autowired
@Qualifier("us")
private TaxCalculation usTax;


public void calculateTaxes(Client client) {
   if (client.isFromIndia()) {
      indiaTax.calculate(client);
   } else if (client.isFromUS()) {
      usTax.calculate(client);
   }
}
```

Comment: `@Bean` isn't used to inject a bean. It's used to declare one. What is needed is `@Autowired`, with `@Qualifier`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the topic below can answer your question. Please refer to
[How to do conditional auto-wiring in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225115/how-to-do-conditional-auto-wiring-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a locator service like:

```
public class ServiceLocator implements ApplicationContextAware
{
  private static ApplicationContext context;
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
  {
    this.context = context;
  }
  public static <T> T getServiceBean(Class<T> serviceClass, String beanName)
  {
    return context.getBean(beanName, serviceClass);
  }
}
```

And your service like:

```
public void calculateTaxes(Client client) 
{
  if (client.isFromIndia())  
  {
    ServiceLocator.getServiceBean(TaxCalculation.class, "indiaTaxBeanName").calculate(client);
  } 
  else if (client.isFromUS())  
 {
    ServiceLocator.getServiceBean(TaxCalculation.class, "usTaxBeanName").calculate(client);
 }
```

}