# Wiring conditional bean in other bean with contructor injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Please go through complete question before marking duplicate. Can discuss more in comments

I have following code where ServiceA depends on ServiceB. And serviceB implementation bean will be conditionally initialized

```
class ServiceA{
   ServiceB serviceB;
   ServiceA(ServiceB serviceB){
      this.serviceB = serviceB;
   }
}


@Configuration
class AppConfig{
   @Conditional("some_condition_based_on_property")
   @Bean
   ServiceB serviceB1(){
     return new ServiceBImpl1();
   }

   @Conditional("some_condition_based_on_property")
   @Bean
   ServiceB serviceB2(){
     return new ServiceBImpl2();
   }

   @Bean
   ServiceA serviceA(){
     //what should go here so that conditional bean is injected in ServiceA
   }

}
```

I cannot auto-detect ServiceA bean, as I need to inject it in a Map with some key. 
One option I see is to remove construction injection, and have serviceB bean @autowired in serviceA, which would be last option for me. Any other option?

Edit: I don't want to have if-else during injection, as the beans can be defined at various places. I will be only using `@Conditional`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225115/how-to-do-conditional-auto-wiring-in-spring ?

Comment: you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225115/how-to-do-conditional-auto-wiring-in-spring

Comment: Updated the question. The related question does not solve my specific problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing holds you from autowiring the resulting `ServiceB` right inside the configuration class and reusing the reference it for creating `ServiceA`:

```
@Configuration
class AppConfig{
   @Conditional(/* some condition */)
   @Bean
   ServiceB serviceB1(){
     return new ServiceBImpl1();
   }

   @Conditional(/* some condition */)
   @Bean
   ServiceB serviceB2(){
     return new ServiceBImpl2();
   }

   // store a local reference    
   @Autowired
   private dynamicServiceB;

   @Bean
   ServiceA serviceA(){
     return new ServiceA(dynamicServiceB);
   }
}
```

However, it feels like you're trying to work around some other problem that you didn't describe, especially given you included syntactically incorrect code: `@Conditional` doesn't accept strings as values. You should not expect that constraining acceptable solutions to those working with a broken bit of code you have will yield much success.

This feels like a scenario for a `@Profile`.