# How to let user to decide which implementation to use for interface in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I'm developing an SDK, which will be used to create additional applications for batch processing. There is *core-a-api* module, which holds interface *Client*

```java
public interface Client {
    void send();
}
```

and *core-a-impl* which holds couple implementations for *Client* interface - *HttpClient* and *TcpClient*.
Also, there is one more core module *core-b-impl*, which uses a particular instance of *Client* interface.

```java
public class SendingTasklet implements Tasklet {
    @Autowired
    private Client client
    
    public void process() {
        client.send();
    } 
}
```

What instance should be created (*HttpClient* or *SftpClient*) should be decided by the user, who creates an application using SDK. They also need to have an ability to create its own implementation for *Client* and use it in *SendingTasklet*. A user from core dependencies can see only interfaces from *-api* modules. For dependency injection, I'm using Spring. All beans for particular modules are created in each module separately. The user created beans are created in user's configuration class

```java
@Configuration
public class UsersApplicationConf {
   
    @Bean
    public Client client {
        return new UsersClient();
    } 
}
```

The issue is, that somehow without exposing *-impl* module details for user application, they should be able to decide what Client implementation can be used from the core provided implementations or they should be able to pass one of their own.

The first thought was to use qualifiers when injecting into *SendingTasklet*, but then you need to create a separate instance variable for each implementation in *SendingTasklet* and this is not very good because if there would be more implementations for *Client* interface it would be required to change *SendingTasklet* as well. And also the problem, that user should somehow decide which implementation to use persists.

What I did, I exposed *core-a-impl* for client's application. So in his configuration, they can decide what instance to create for *Client* interface.

```java
@Configuration
public class UsersApplicationConf {
   
    @Bean
    public Client client {
        return new HttpClient();
    }
```

}

But this is not very smart as well and I'm thinking is there any other way how to solve this issue?

Comment: I think, you can implement a conditional autowiring bean. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225115/how-to-do-conditional-auto-wiring-in-spring

Answer (score 1):

You can use strategy or factory pattern as mentioned [here](http://kh-yiu.blogspot.cz/2013/04/spring-implementing-factory-pattern.html) but personally I would go with JSR 330 that you can find an example [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/04/a-quality-qualifier) , below code block for spring example:

```
package spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static spring.Spring.Platform;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Spring {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Spring.class);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Platform(Platform.OperatingSystems.ANDROID)
    private MarketPlace android;

    @Autowired
    @Platform(Platform.OperatingSystems.IOS)
    private MarketPlace ios;

    @PostConstruct
    public void qualifyTheTweets() {
        System.out.println("ios:" + this.ios);
        System.out.println("android:" + this.android);
    }

    // the type has to be public!
    @Target({ElementType.FIELD,
            ElementType.METHOD,
            ElementType.TYPE,
            ElementType.PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Qualifier
    public static @interface Platform {

        OperatingSystems value();

        public static enum OperatingSystems {
            IOS,
            ANDROID
        }
    }
}

interface MarketPlace {
}

@Component
@Platform(Platform.OperatingSystems.IOS)
class AppleMarketPlace implements MarketPlace {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "apple";
    }
}

@Component
@Platform(Platform.OperatingSystems.ANDROID)
class GoogleMarketPlace implements MarketPlace {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "android";
    }
}
```

> Edit:  I didnt test the code but I have used javax.inject.Qualifier
>   with CDI if this code doesnt work let me know I will update with
>   correct combination and imports