# Conditional Autowiring in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to do conditional auto-wiring in Spring using annotation-based configuration. I have 2 different beans both implementing the same interface. I would like to do something like

if(some condition) 
choose bean 1 to autowire
else
choose bean 2 to autowire

Is there a way to do this? I noticed the @Primary and @Qualifier annotations, but they will only choose one bean or the other to autowire and not based on some condition. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225115/how-to-do-conditional-auto-wiring-in-spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autowiring injects a bean into the target bean only once, when the target object is being initialized. Afterwards it remain unchanged.

Consider other approaches. For instance, inject both beans and implement a method that selects one of these beans depending on your conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mentallurg. That looks to be working for me. I have made one bean primary and put the conditional logic in a separate method.