# Spring Boot - How to Create Factory of different JpaRepository Interfaces

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a service layer that Autowires a repository like so

```
@Service
public class OrderService {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository repository;

    public List<Order> retrieveOrders(String storeId) {
        try {

            return repository.getOrders(storeId)

        } catch(Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I have new requirement that, depending on the store number, the repository query logic should change. I'm thinking of abstracting my repository and using a factory pattern. The current repository is an interface and extends JpaRepository; further more all of its functions are using @Query annotation to define the JPQL. This is an example with just one function, but there are several functions in my actual Repository

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository {

    @Query("select o " +
        " from Orders o " +
        " where o.storeId = :storeId")
    public List<Order> getOrders(@Param(value = "storeId") String storeId);

}
```

The new requirements state that for a specific storeId, the SQL needs to change to something like this:

```
public interface OrderRepositoryStore886 extends JpaRepository {

    @Query("select o " +
        " from Order o " +
        " where o.storeId = :storeId " +
        "     and o.status IN (1,3,10,15) " +
        "     and EXISTS (SELECT c from CollabOrder WHERE c.orderId = o.orderId)")
    public List<Order> getOrders(@Param(value = "storeId") String storeId);

}
```

However all remaining stores should use the first SQL query.

I am trying to figure out how to conditionally @Autowire the repository based on storeId. I was thinking of creating a factory but I don't know how to make a factory that returns interface objects (I am still fairly new to java, this might be trivial but I've yet to figure it out). And if I try to turn the Repository interface into a class, it forces me to Override all of the abstract JpaRepository methods which is unnecessary extra code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do conditional auto-wiring in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225115/how-to-do-conditional-auto-wiring-in-spring)

Comment: It might be helpful if my Repository objects were classes, but since they are interfaces, I don't know how to apply the accepted answer in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already on the right track. I would solve the problem but creating a factory method that returns the right bean interface.

The only drawback with this method is that you can't Autowire you beans. You should instantiate them on the fly.

```
create table orders
(
  id                      integer      not null,
  constraint pk_orders primary key(id)
);

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
public class Order {

    @Id
    private long id;
}


public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT t FROM Order t")
    Order getOrder(String storeId);
}


@Repository
public interface OrderRepositoryStore100 extends OrderRepository {
    @Query("SELECT t FROM Order t WHERE t.id = 100")
    Order getOrder(@Param(value = "id") String storeId);
}

@Repository
public interface OrderRepositoryStore286 extends OrderRepository {
    @Query("SELECT t FROM Order t WHERE t.id = 286")
    Order getOrder(@Param(value = "id") String storeId);
}

public class OrderRepositoryStoreFactory {

    private static final String REPOSITORY_BASE_NAME = "orderRepositoryStore";

    public static OrderRepository getRepository(ApplicationContext context, String storeId) {

        return (OrderRepository) context.getBean(REPOSITORY_BASE_NAME + storeId);
    }
}

@Service
public class OrderService {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public Order retrieveOrders(String storeId) {
        try {

            OrderRepository repository = OrderRepositoryStoreFactory.getRepository(context, storeId);

            return repository.getOrder(storeId);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}



@SpringBootApplication
public class FactoryApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FactoryApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Order order = orderService.retrieveOrders("100");
        System.out.println(order);

        order = orderService.retrieveOrders("286");
        System.out.println(order);
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

2020-05-03 20:23:34.567  INFO 33955 --- [           main] com.factory.FactoryApplication           : Started FactoryApplication in 3.003 seconds (JVM running for 3.615)
Order(id=**100**)
Order(id=**286**)

Hope this helps

Comment: It's possible I am missing something, because I am getting "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '<repositoryName>' available"  (In this example <repositoryName> would be either orderRepositoryStore100 or orderRepositoryStore886). I verified they both have the @Repository annotation

Comment: Please check my answer again, I have added a fully functional example. If you still have the problem, it would be great if you share more code.

Comment: Thank you. Since you last posted I tried using @ Component instead of @ Repository and it worked (but maked no sense since to me since @ Repository is a type of @ Component). Toyed around with some other stuff and now @ Repository works. At this point I conceded I have no idea what I'm doing, and throwing darts blindly and seeing what sticks :)

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to ask any question that bothers you.

Comment: Just a heads up, I wasn't able to get the OrderRepositoryStoreFactory tests to work using this way. However I replaced context.getBean() with JpaRepositoryFactory.getRepository() and now it works

Comment: That's great to hear.