# How to inject this or that implementation depending on configuration a parameter with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, configuration

I am using the Spring/Springboot framework and would like to know if there is a possibility to "choose" or "select" the implementation class to instanciate depending on a configuration parameter

Let's say I have an interface `IMyInterface` and two possible implementations `IImplentation1` and `IImplementation2`

I also have a class `FooBar` whose constructor receives a configuration class `MyConf` and an instance of `IMyInterface`

```
@Component
interface IMyInterface {
}

class  IImplentation1 implements IMyInterface {
}

@Component
class  IImplentation2 implements IMyInterface {
}



@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("my.application")
@Validated
class MyConf {
   String kind; /// could be an enum
}

class  IImplentation2 implements IMyInterface {
}


@Component
class FooBar {

    @Autowired
    public FooBar(MyConf myConf,
                  IMyInterface myInterface) { /// IImplentation1 or IImplentation2
        ...                                   /// depending on MyConf.kind
    }

}
```

Thanks for help

Regards
Philippe

Comment: Is this what you're after?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350865/spring-choose-bean-implementation-at-runtime

Comment: This might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225115/how-to-do-conditional-auto-wiring-in-spring

Comment: `@ConditionalOnProperty`?